# fetch data with flutter Receiver: null error

Tags: json, flutter, dart, fetch, flutter-layout

i try to fetch api json , here is the link https://api.myjson.com/bins/ut9kq
when i print the output before the loop it does get the data but after the list it give me error

"Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'image' was called on null.
E/flutter (30730): Receiver: null
E/flutter (30730): Tried calling: image"

here is my code

```
    List lists;

    Future<List> getLists() async {
      lists = new List();
      await api.httpGet('bins/ut9kq').then((reponse) {
        var data = jsonDecode(reponse.body);
        print(data); // i get the json data => [{},{}..]
        data.forEach((l) {
          lists.add(ArticleModal().fromJson(l));
        });
        // print(lists[0].image);//Receiver: null
      });
      return lists;
    }
```

Comment: well i always work with it and it works like charm .. i don't see any difference (instead of calling the model and setting a name for it ) , is there a performence issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using both approaches for future handling, .then callbacks and async and await. Try the following, you can wrap these around try/catch blocks for error handling.

```
Future<List<ArticleModal>> getLists() async {
  lists = new List();

  var response = await http.get('bins/ut9kq');

  // a switch may be used for a wider range of codes
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    print(decodedResponse);
    //if response is a collection
    var listAricleModal = (decodedResponse as List).map((collectionElement) => ArticleModal.fromJson(collectionElement)).toList();
    return listAricleModal;
  }
  //Your future is an empty collection
  return [];
}
```

And to properly answer your question, `image` is called on null is quite obvious message.
At some point you have an `image` field, that object is not created. Probably is the object in the list, so two things may be happening:

- List is empty, so nothing to call image on.
- There is a problem when calling fromJson.

Either way, use the debugger and set breakpoints on each method first line to clearly understand what is happening.
If map function is tricky to debug, use a plain for loop until you know where the bug is.

Check out this series of videos from Google.
https://youtu.be/vl_AaCgudcY

Also official docs: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: well thank you for your answer i found the issue and it was so stupid of me .. i forgot the return in articlemodel class.. + i still don't know how to use debugger tho , can please give me some nice tuto

Comment: Check the official docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging